# Default variables with python-dotenv

Tags: python, environment-variables, python-dotenv

I want to make a package that works out of the box with reasonable default variables, like defining some servers, ports etc. so that the code works for an average user like he expects it without further configuration.
But I want this environment variables to be overriden if a .env file exists in order to allow configuration for other environments.
I read that python-dotenv load_values will use defaults if no .env file exists, but there is no example on pypi how that would set up ideally.

Comment: Did you see the example involving the construction of a dict using `dotenv_values` and `os.environ`?

Comment: Do you mean the second block in other usecases?

Comment: @chepner I tried to answer it myself with your hint. Maybe you can have a look.

Comment: That's exactly right. It's not for `dotenv` to provide defaults, but for the application to *use* `dotenv` to override defaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the comment of @chepner I think there might be a solution using merge. Didn't know about that feature yet.

```py
from dotenv import dotenv_values


default_envs = {"MY_SERVER": "https://my-server.com"}
config = {
    **default_envs,
    **dotenv_values
}
```

This might be nice, because it allows for partial override and I don't need to go through all variables.

Comments are welcome.

Comment: Note: `dotenv_values` is a function, did you perhaps forget to put the brackets for the function call in the answer?

Comment: You are probably right. Don't use that solution and went with using toml for config.

Answer (score 1):

i think this way would work.

```
default_dict = {'API_KEY':'test'} #e.x for an api_key 

try:
    load_dotenv(find_dotenv())
    api_key = os.getenv("API_KEY")
except:
    api_key = default_dict['API_KEY']
```

Comment: That would be an idea, thx.

Comment: Don't use a bare `except`: at least use `except Exception`, if not an even more specific exception class for what you expect could be raised.

Comment: `os.getenv("API_KEY", default_dict['API_KEY']` removes the need for the try-except.

Answer (score 0):

python_dotenv is just convenient way to load variable to environment

You can add an option to override an already existing env variable:

```
load_dotenv(override=True)
```

The order how env are defined can be found [here](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv?tab=readme-ov-file#variable-expansion).

To load the default value, just use `os.getenv` implementation

```
os.getenv(key, default = 'string value, or define None')
```

Although, you might not define value in order to make this work (define only key, without using `=`)